# Are edits removing tags frowned upon?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, moderation, retagging

I tried to remove the tag "set-theory" tag from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4529234/how-would-you-calculate-the-speed-of-a-bouncing-ball-that-loses-energy-with-each) because I thought it was blatantly wrong but my edit was [rejected by two reviewers](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1841808). Does that mean that those reviewers are opposed to removing tags under any circumstances except possibly by the original author?

Comment: Unless those two reviewers see this post and choose to comment there's no way of knowing.  I would say that you were right to remove the tag; that said, your comment asking why the tag was applied in the first place is also a good option.  Try not to get too worked up over a mis-tagging though... like misplacing a book on a library shelf, it's inconvenient for some but hardly a catastrophe :)

Comment: See MSE's FAQ: "[How do I correctly tag my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18878/282094)". If you are certain that you have edited correctly then you can "[rollback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17038/282094)", (see the section: "Can I provide a reason for rolling back?", and link to this question). Any further edits will trigger an automatic flag, and a moderator will decide the outcome. Note that the OP can decline the edit (which is not the case here), usually that weighs in their favor; unless they are undeniably wrong. - A *better* edit would have added an additional tag.

Comment: @Rob it looks like some of what you wrote doesn't quite match up with the situation here. For instance, there's nothing to rollback to here (Arvid's suggested edit would have been the first edit to the post, and the post was originally incorrectly tagged). The proposed edit is completely fine on the tagging front and shouldn't need an additional tag to be approved.

Comment: @KReiser, read the comment again; and the section referred to: by *rolling* and leaving **both** a reason and a change, the roll becomes an edit. **That's** a roll to where Arvid had it previously. --- The optional *complete* edit, of improving the tags, could be done as follows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t84rj.png - I said it wasn't required, I only suggested that it might have been the basis for the reviewer's incorrect rejection - if they don't chime in we can only guess their reasons. --- We might *know* the rejection is incorrect because a moderator has now made the edit.

Comment: @Rob again, when the edit was proposed, there was no other version of the post to roll back to besides the original, which contained the incorrect tag (see [timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4529234/timeline)). This advice may be useful in general, but I do not see how it applies to the specific post under consideration in this discussion.

Comment: Perhaps this is a simpler explanation: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/28164/510296 - and again, yes, advice that is both specific and general helps more people than specific or general advice alone. Perhaps the reviewers wanted the grammatical error to be addressed too, not everyone has time for pendants over precision; nor the ability to apply what is presented to the situation at hand, to read in scope and context.

Comment: Honestly, it looks to me like the reviewers who rejected the edit were not paying all that much attention, as the "right" reject reason for tag edits includes language about irrelevant tags.  So my feeling is that two people made a mistake.  It happens.  I wouldn't read too much into it.

Answer (score 24):

Edits removing tags are not generally frowned on.  If a question seems to you to be incorrectly tagged, edit it to correct the tags.  This includes cases where you add new tags, remove existing tags, or both.